# Flutter: How can i extract a specific value out of the Huawei Settings App?

Tags: android, flutter, huawei-developers

If I am charging my Huawei Phone and go to Settings --> Battery there is at the Top a Value, that shows how mach time my Phone needs until it is fully charged. My Question now is, if there is a way to extract this value with Flutter and use it in my App?[The Battery value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLtXH.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [battery_level](https://pub.dev/packages/battery_info) package for get information about a device battery state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the battery level from a huawei phone. Use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/battery. It will help grab the battery level information and allow you to use and manipulate it in flutter.

I tested this on honor v30 and it works fine.

[image]